# Do I need to declare functions before they are used in the same namespace in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have this code snippet:

```
(ns mylib-clojure.core)

(defn doWhatever2 [x]
  (doWhatever1 x))

(defn doWhatever1 [x]
  (inc x))
```

This code doesn't work unless I move `doWhatever1` function definition to above `doWhatever2`. It seems weird I have to do this since I am in the same namespace. Is there a way to declare my functions in a namespace without having to mind about order?

Comment: If Clojure didn't behave this way, you couldn't just copy-and-paste any namespace from a file into the REPL and expect it to work (because the REPL has no possible way to do multi-pass compilation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Clojure compiler does a single pass so order does matter.

Clojure does provide a way to specify forward declarations:

```
(declare doWhatever1)
```

See [clojure.core/declare](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/declare)